# Get data based of child val realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My current databse layout for each user]

Here is my database layout. I am currently getting data from it by using: `myRef.child(userid).child("UserName").get().addOnSuccessListener {`

This works great for getting the needed value, in this case the users name "Josh". I can then set the text view on his profile as displaying his name by using this:

```
        val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Nameuser)
        myRef.child(userid).child("UserName").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got value ${it.value}")
            name.setText("Name: ${it.value}")
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }
```

I need to get the dislikes values that are true so that his profile displays a list of his dislikes. My original attempt was by using the same method as the name but changing the path from "UserName" to "Dislikes", this returned a list of all the values true and false in the dislikes section. I only need/want the true values so I added `.equalTo(true)` so it looked like:

```
        val dislikes = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Dislikes)
        myRef.child(userid).child("Dislikes").equalTo(true).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got value dis ${it.value}")
            dislikes.setText("Dislikes: ${it.value}")
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }
```

But this crashes with the following.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using orderByPriority(), values provided to startAt(), startAfter(), endAt(), endBefore(), or equalTo() must be valid priorities.`

How can I fix this error? Or is there another way to get and sort only the true values from the database and get them to an array for use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries consist of two operations:

1. A call to `orderBy...`, which tells the database to order the child nodes on a specific value.
2. A call to `equalTo`, `startAt`, `endAt`, etc, which tells the database to subsequently filter the child nodes based on the values it previously sorted them on.

Your code contains #2, but it doesn't contain any instruction to order the data. While this is valid syntactically (otherwise the SDK would've raised an error) it doesn't do what you need.

In your case, you want to order/filter on the value of the childes nodes under `Dislikes`, so that's be:

```
myRef.child(userid).child("Dislikes").orderByValue().equalTo(true)...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Its informative and makes sense however I now have another issue. I get the error ```Index not defined, add ".indexOn": ".value", for path ... , to the rules```. I understand I have to add indexing to the path for this users dislikes to the rules for it to work however what about if another user with a different auth key tries to access theirs? Won't this will have a different path so the error will occur for that user? Is there any way to add indexing to the entire database or automate adding the new path to the rules?

Comment: ok, will do then!